# No se leer el explain de Postgres para optimizar las consultas

Tags: postgresql, symfony3, pgadmin, doctrine2

Tengo la siguiente DQL que genera su respectivo SQL:

```
SELECT b, eob, teob, c, prov, perf, m, st, eom FROM AppBundle:Bulto b JOIN b.estructuraBulto eob JOIN eob.tipoEstructuraOrganizativa teob JOIN b.colaborador c JOIN c.provinciaCuba prov JOIN c.perfilColaborador perf JOIN c.menaje m JOIN m.status st JOIN m.estructuraMenaje eom WHERE c.id = :id ORDER BY b.numero ASC
```

El SQL resultante:

```
SELECT b0_.id AS id_0, b0_.numero AS numero_1, b0_.descripcion AS descripcion_2, b0_.contiene_un_solo_articulo AS contiene_un_solo_articulo_3, b0_.dimension_largo AS dimension_largo_4, b0_.dimension_ancho AS dimension_ancho_5, b0_.dimension_alto AS dimension_alto_6, b0_.peso_volumetrico AS peso_volumetrico_7, b0_.peso AS peso_8, b0_.volumen AS volumen_9, b0_.precio_a_costometrocubico_actual AS precio_a_costometrocubico_actual_10, b0_.internal_id AS internal_id_11, c1_.id AS id_12, c1_.es_jefe_contenedor AS es_jefe_contenedor_13, c1_.primer_nombre AS primer_nombre_14, c1_.segundo_nombre AS segundo_nombre_15, c1_.apellido_uno AS apellido_uno_16, c1_.apellido_dos AS apellido_dos_17, c1_.pasaporte AS pasaporte_18, c1_.numero_identidad AS numero_identidad_19, c1_.telefono_cuba AS telefono_cuba_20, c1_.direccion_venezuela AS direccion_venezuela_21, c1_.telefono_venezuela AS telefono_venezuela_22, c1_.direccion_cuba AS direccion_cuba_23, c1_.persona_responsable AS persona_responsable_24, c1_.telefono_persona_responsable AS telefono_persona_responsable_25, c1_.email_contacto AS email_contacto_26, c1_.fecha_inicio_mision AS fecha_inicio_mision_27, c1_.fecha_fin_mision AS fecha_fin_mision_28, c1_.finalizo_mision AS finalizo_mision_29, c1_.internal_id AS internal_id_30, c1_.numero_de_orden AS numero_de_orden_31, c1_.lista_bultos_bloqueada AS lista_bultos_bloqueada_32, c1_.lista_empaque_bloqueada AS lista_empaque_bloqueada_33, p2_.id AS id_34, p2_.nombre AS nombre_35, p2_.sigla AS sigla_36, p3_.id AS id_37, p3_.nombre AS nombre_38, e4_.id AS id_39, e4_.title AS title_40, e4_.lft AS lft_41, e4_.lvl AS lvl_42, e4_.rgt AS rgt_43, e4_.internal_id AS internal_id_44, t5_.id AS id_45, t5_.nombre AS nombre_46, b0_.estructura_bulto_id AS estructura_bulto_id_47, b0_.colaborador_id AS colaborador_id_48, c1_.estructura_colaborador_id AS estructura_colaborador_id_49, c1_.menaje_id AS menaje_id_50, c1_.provincia_cuba AS provincia_cuba_51, c1_.perfil_colaborador_id AS perfil_colaborador_id_52, e4_.tipo_estructura_organizativa_id AS tipo_estructura_organizativa_id_53, e4_.tree_root AS tree_root_54, e4_.parent_id AS parent_id_55, e4_.usuario_asociado_id AS usuario_asociado_id_56 FROM bulto b0_ INNER JOIN colaborador c1_ ON b0_.colaborador_id = c1_.id INNER JOIN provincia_cuba p2_ ON c1_.provincia_cuba = p2_.id INNER JOIN perfil_colaborador p3_ ON c1_.perfil_colaborador_id = p3_.id INNER JOIN estructura_organizativa e4_ ON b0_.estructura_bulto_id = e4_.id INNER JOIN tipo_estructura_organizativa t5_ ON e4_.tipo_estructura_organizativa_id = t5_.id WHERE e4_.id = 500
```

y el gráfico que devuelve el PGAdmin del Explain query es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Favor explicarme el gráfico, y según la dql, si es necesario realizar alguna optimización

Comment: como primer paso, todos esos join sin condiciones (que son productos cartesianos) estan bien?

Comment: @gbianchi, hago los joins para obtener los registros asociados de las relación 1-M

Comment: Si pero son sin condiciones... o la base de datos la infiere.. si no... es un producto cartesiano

Comment: @gbianchi agregué el SQL resultante de la DQL anterior